# UIImageView autoresizingmask not working in certain cases

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimageview, autolayout, uikit, autoresizingmask

I am experimenting with a block-breaking iOS app to learn more about UI features.  Currently, I am having issues trying to make it work for screen rotation.

I am able to get the blocks to re-arrange properly after screen rotation but am having trouble with getting the UIImageView for the paddle re-arrange.

My code is split as follows, VC calls initializes an object of the BlockModel class.  This object stores a CGRect property (which is the CGRect corresponding to the paddle's ImageView).

The VC then creates an imageView initialized with the paddle image, sets the autoresinging property on the image view (to have flexible external masks), sets the frame based on the CGRect in the model object and adds the imageView as a sub-view of the main view being handled by the VC.

The code is below.

When I rotate, I am seeing that the ImageView is not being automatically repositioned.

If I do all the image view and CGRect creation in the vC, then it works (code sample 2).

Is this expected behavior? If yes, why is autoresizing not kicking in if the CGRect is obtained from a property in another object?

Full Xcode project code is [here](https://github.com/smartiothome/BlockBreakeriOS) (github link)

**EDIT**
Looks like things don't work if I store the imageView as a property.  I was doing this to have quick access to it.  Why doesn't it work if imageView is stored as a property?

**Code where model is initialized**

```
self.myModel = [[BlockerModel alloc] initWithScreenWidth:self.view.bounds.size.width                                         andHeight:self.view.bounds.size.height];
```

**Model initialization code**

```
-(instancetype) initWithScreenWidth:(CGFloat)width andHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.screenWidth = width;
        self.screenHeight = height;
        UIImage* paddleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle.png"];
        CGSize paddleSize = [paddleImage size];
        self.paddleRect = CGRectMake((self.screenWidth-paddleSize.width)/2, (1 - PADDLE_BOTTOM_OFFSET)*self.screenHeight, paddleSize.width, paddleSize.height);
    }

    return self;
}
```

**Code in VC where imageView is initialized**

```
self.paddleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle"]];
self.paddleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.paddleView.opaque = NO;
self.paddleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
NSLog(@"Paddle rect is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.myModel.paddleRect));
[self.paddleView setFrame:self.myModel.paddleRect];
[self.view addSubview:self.paddleView];
```

**If I instead use this code in the VC to initialize imageView things work**

```
    UIImage* paddleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle.png"];
    CGSize paddleSize = [paddleImage size];

    CGRect paddleRect = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width-paddleSize.width)/2, (1 - PADDLE_BOTTOM_OFFSET)*self.view.bounds.size.height, paddleSize.width, paddleSize.height);
    UIImageView *paddleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:paddleImage];
    paddleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    paddleView.opaque = NO;
    paddleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    [paddleView setFrame:paddleRect];
    [self.view addSubview:paddleView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  I was using the model object to handle all my "game object location" logic.  E.g VC would calculate the X axis deltas from the touch events & forward them to the model object.  Also, CADisplayLink events would be forwarded so that model can update ball location based on velocity and time since last event.  It will then use updated location to detect collisions.  This split was used because model class also had the methods to detect collisions with sides, paddle/ball etc.

The issue was that the model object was rewriting the CGRect of the paddleView by adding the delta it received from VC to the origin.x of current paddleRect it had stored.  This paddleRect did not take into account the automatic adjustment to the CGRect that is done by auto-resizing after a rotation.

The fix was for the VC to set the CGRect of the paddleRect (set to paddleView frame) before calling the method in the model to update all the game properties and detect collisions.  This way model only takes care of logic of collusion detection and updating ball movement and velocity based on it.  The VC uses current paddleView location and hence automatically accounts for the automatic adjustment to the CGRect that is done by auto-resizing after a rotation.

Source code in github link updated.